# MSK connector to handshake with a third party hosted cluster using Kafka SSL or SASL Authentication

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, aws-msk, aws-msk-connect

I have created a kinesis source connector which is supposed to pull data from the **kinesis** stream and push the same data to **kafka topic**.

The use case here is connector will be deployed on **Amazon MSK connect** and where as the topic is created on some **other kafka cluster** which is hosted on **Azure**.

The roadblocker I have is the authentication related properties are not supported on MSK connect **worker configurations**, Is there any other way where we can integrate kafka security using MSK connect?

Below are the properties which are not supported **MSK connect**

```
admin.
admin.listeners.https.
client.
connect.
inter.worker.
internal.
listeners.https.
metrics.
metrics.context.
rest.
sasl.
security.
socket.
ssl.
topic.tracking.
worker.
bootstrap.servers
config.storage.topic
connections.max.idle.ms
connector.client.config.override.policy
group.id
listeners
metric.reporters
plugin.path
receive.buffer.bytes
response.http.headers.config
scheduled.rebalance.max.delay.ms
send.buffer.bytes
status.storage.topic
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, none of these properties are specific to MSK https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connectconfigs .. If you want to add Azure auth to Kafka Connect, you'll probably have to run it yourself in EC2 or containers to add Azure specific classes or TLS certificates for that Kafka cluster to the JVM classpath